# How do I fit everything inside html and body

Tags: html, css

I have a project and I am having trouble fitting everything inside the `body`. Child elements always go outside of the `body`, when I looked at my code it looks like okay, so I made an experiment; I trace each HTML element by giving them a border, so that I can see them visually how they will behave. This is what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>A nice example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="childbox"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Example 1**, setting 100% height for everything

```
html{height: 100%; border: 5px solid black; padding: 5px;} /*black*/
body{height: 100%; border: 5px solid red; padding: 10px;} /*red*/
.box{height: 100%; border: 5px solid green; padding: 5px;} /*green*/
.childbox{height: 100%; border: 5px solid pink} /*pink*/
```

**Output** : everything overflows outside html.

**CSS Example 2**, setting 100% height for the body and its child's, except html

```
html{border: 5px solid black; padding: 5px;} /*black*/
body{height: 100%; border: 5px solid red; padding: 10px;} /*red*/
.box{height: 100%; border: 5px solid green; padding: 5px;} /*green*/
.childbox{height: 100%; border: 5px solid pink} /*pink*/
```

**Output** : Everything fits inside `html`, but doesn't occupy the full height of the screen. I know I can do this by making the body `min-height: 100vh`.. but it will stop expanding when the 100vh is full..

My goal is,

1. to make the body and html 100% in height / not using vh.
2. and not overflow outside the body, or html
3. when adding child elements I want everything from html to body expands in height dynamically and not go outside and overflow, or overlaps each other..
4. the body should be inside html, and the div's should be inside the body.

Please help.

Comment: Watch your language. This isn't reddit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is happening, the CSS is calculating 100% width and height and then it adds a 10px / 5px padding after which causes the elements to overflow by 10 / 5px.
You can change this by adding the following css at the beginning of your code:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  //Edit:
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This will make sure that the padding is accounted for in the 100% width and height.
Hope this works!

**Edit:**
Also, what you are looking for in the `html` and `body` style is `height: auto;` not 100%.

Comment: you will also need to remember that everything has a margin and padding by default and you need to add `*{margin: 0; padding: 0}` as the first line of your css.  This should get rid of your overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

If its happening it means that you are not following CSS box model during styling your sheet. you can also use box-sizing property of CSS.

Consider an example

```
<div id="frame">This is the frame
</div>
```

Then use box-sizing property and set its value to border-box.

```
<style>
#frame{  width: xx% height:yy%; box-sizing:border-box; }
</style>
```